# Button with 2 colors as a border

Tags: css, button

I'm trying to create a button that has two colors as a border.
The two colors i need used are blue: #00a7e1, orange: #f6531d.

I would like to just use css if possible.

Thank in advance!

[**link to button concept**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELg2v.png)

Comment: Have you attempted anything? Please share what you've tried along with the code.

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```css
.btn
{
    border: 0;

    padding: 4px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: linear-gradient(20deg, #00a7e1 49%, #e65300 50%);
}
.bg
{
    background: #349645;
    padding: 8px 14px;
    font: bold 24px Consolas;
}
.btn:active .bg
{
    background: #0a1117;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn"><div class="bg">YOU'R TITLE</div></div>
<button class="btn"><div class="bg">YOU'R TITLE</div></div>
```

Comment: He said that he wants to do only css if possible.

Comment: @SamyokNepal Is only css. What you see and is not css ?

Comment: It's not a button, and it has a wrapper div. There might be situations (eg. some blogs) that only allow custom CSS and not custom HTML. Of course, this is the simpler method if you can edit HTML.

Comment: Rename the first div to button and set 'border: 0;' to .btn and is button. not hard.

Answer (score 1):

You may also play with [gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient) and [background-clip](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip) *(see comments in CSS)*

```css
button {
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 5px solid transparent;/* give extra space for gradients colors */
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  margin: 0.25em;
  padding: 0.5em 2em;
  background: linear-gradient(#333, #333),/* black turned into gradient to hold with background-clip and hide the 2 color gradient under it */
    linear-gradient(/* 2 colors to draw under the borders also via background-clip*/
        to bottom left,
        rgb(230, 83, 0) 50%,
        gray 51%,
        rgb(0, 166, 224) 40%
      )
      no-repeat center center;
  background-clip: 
    padding-box, /* drawn inside including padding area */
    border-box;/* drawn also under borders */
  background-size:
  100% 100%, 
  110% 150%;/* must be bigger than 100% so it include also borders, else it repeats */
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px black, inset 0 0 2px black;/* did you want this too ? */
}
```

```html
<button>BUTTON</button> <button> TO</button> <button> PLAY</button>
```

If you think this is too much, you also have [border-image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image-width) .

Comment: Yes I think  it's too much :p

Comment: @TemaniAfif nop , really too much would be this piece of art http://diana-adrianne.com/purecss-francine/ , but i still  agree here when border-image will do it from a single line ;) it was for the fun and give some things to chew on to the op :) I was surprised nobody proposed border-image yet ...

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `border-image` with a gradient:

```css
button {
  padding:20px;
  border:5px solid;
  border-image:linear-gradient(60deg,#00a7e1 50%,#f6531d 0) 20;
  background:transparent;
}
```

```html
<button>some text</button>
```

Comment: The only thing I would point out with this is that it is IE11+

Comment: @zero298 yes but who care about IE? .. not me ;)